# How will the map be described?

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory, fundamental-groups, free-product

Collapsing either one of the circles in the bouquet of two circles to the basepoint, how can I describe this by a map (in the free product) and how is this related to that $\mathbb{R}^2\backslash\{p,q\}$ is **not** homeomorphic to a bouquet of two circles! However there is a **deformation retraction** of that space to a subspace homeomorphic to the bouquet of two circles?

Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Please add some more context on what you've tried. Do you understand why the fundamental group is the free product?

Comment: I am not so sure about what you mean by "how can I describe this by a map (in the free product)". For the second question, I think they are not homeomorphic because of, for example, compactness.

Comment: @Karl yes I do, I just need to write maps and show that they are well defined under the equivalence relation I have.

Comment: @Ja_1941 In the second case I also want to write a map and show that it is well defined under my equivalence relation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you try to write down the homomorphism induced by the collapsing map from the figure eight to the collapsed space which is a circle, it would be enough to write down the images of the two generators of the fundamental group of the figure eight which is a free group of over 2 generators. Then the homomorphism takes one of the generators to 0 (which corresponds to the collapsed circle) and another one to identity (which corresponds to the intact circle).

For the 2nd question it would be enough to point out that wedge of 2 circles is compact whereas plane without 2 points is not.

Comment: I do not know what you mean by explicit description of the homomorphism. It is enough to define the homomorphism on the generators. In this case the generator $a$ goes to $0$ and thr other generator $b$ goes to $b$.